# Typescript parent reference

Tags: object, recursion, typescript, interface

I have a recursive TS object that i'm using for building a tree.

Here is the interface definition:

```
export interface UIItem
{
    EnumValue    : myEnum;
    children    ?: Array<UIItem>;
    expanded     : boolean;
}
```

I need to navigate back from child to parent.
Is there a better way of doing this instead of adding the "parent" property to my interface?

```
export interface UIItem
{
    EnumValue    : myEnum;
    children    ?: Array<UIItem>;
    parent      ?: UIItem;
    expanded     : boolean;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: That depends on your scenario, how you manage the items and so on. For example, you can have a data structure that maps between an item and its parent. If you provide more information about what you're doing it will be easier to answer

Comment: I only use this object to pilot the UI, to build a tree on parents-children...
Then i save a monodimensional json

Comment: It's a classical tree problem. There's a tradeoff: you can have the parent information for each item, or you can search from the root to the given child in order to find the parent. Which one to use depends on how often you need to find a parent, and how many items you might have

Comment: My final tree is quite big.. So you're saying that my possible solution could be the best?

Comment: If you often need to get a parent from a child, then yes, that's how I would do it.

Comment: I was also thinking about using a class instead of interface, with a constructor with the parent as argument, but i think it's heavier and not so readable

Comment: If you need to have methods on the items then yeah, go with a class, otherwise (if the items are only for data) then have a factory function which receives the parent as an argument (null for root)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133882/discussion-between-marco-burrometo-and-nitzan-tomer).